# Optimizing conditional styling based on integer values in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I have an integer value representing different output messages to the user, such as error or success messages. Currently, I check if the integer is smaller than 100 to apply "The Error Style" font, and if it's greater than or equal to 100, I apply "The Success Style" font. I want to extend this logic to include additional styles for values over 1000 and so on.

Here's my current implementation:

```
if (m_errorNumber < 100) {
    errorColor.setColor(255, 0, 0, 255);
} else {
    errorColor.setColor(0, 255, 0, 255);
}
```

I'm considering optimizing this by checking the length of the integer instead. For example, if the length is between 1 and 2, or 3, or 4, etc., I would apply the corresponding style. I'm specifically seeking ways to improve performance and find the right case as quickly as possible.

My question is, how can I efficiently determine the appropriate case based on the integer value? Is there a more efficient way then If-Else-Checking?

Comment: If there is a difference, it is likely so small as to not be worth the effort.  Have you profiled your program to see where the actual bottlenecks are?

Comment: You're really underestimating how fast computers can do such trivial operations. I'd imagine something like an `int` comparison would translate to 1 or 2 ASM instructions.

Comment: Also, calculating the "length" will take much, much more time than `if ... else ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my detailed question is, how I can find the right case as fast as I can?

You have very few *"if smaller than ... else"* rules, so **performance is not an issue** and there is no way, nor any need to increase speed. A series of `if`s does the job well enough. Unless you've actually measured speed and detected a bottleneck, of course.

From a computer-science point of view, however, it is possible to come up with a solution which offers better computational complexity, such that the number of necessary comparison operations will be proportionally reduced the larger your *n* gets, i.e. the more rules you have.

---

Let's see. Your *"if smaller than ... else"* rules constitute certain ranges, and the bodies of your `if`s all perform the same operation with different arguments.

This scenario can be pictured as a map in which the end of each range is mapped to an argument set. In C++:

```
struct ColorArguments { int a; int b; int c; int d; };
std::map<int, ColorArguments> ranges;
```

The map would then be filled as follows:

```
ranges[100] = { 255, 0 , 0 , 255 };
ranges[1000] = { 0, 255 , 0 , 255 };
ranges[std::numeric_limits<int>::max()] = { 0, 0, 0, 255 };
```

In fact, instead of filling it, you should rather initialise it and make it `const`:

```
std::map<int, ColorArguments> const ranges = {
    { 100,                             { 255, 0   , 0, 255 } },
    { 1000,                            { 0,   255 , 0, 255 } },
    { std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), { 0,   0,    0, 255 } }
};
```

Finally, the [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound) member function can be used to give you the appropriate `ColorArguments` objects. The function returns an iterator to the first element whose key is greater than the specified value.

For example, in this map, searching for 500 would give you a pointer to the element with key 1000, because 1000 is the first key greater than 500.

`upper_bound` has **logarithmic complexity**, which is pretty good and better than the linear complexity of your original `if-else` chains, notwithstanding potential compiler optimisations which may translate that linear code into something more complex.

```
auto const iter = ranges.upper_bound(m_errorNumber);
auto const& colors = iter->second;
```

Note how using `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` (the maximum possible `int` on your machine) as a key in the map avoids special handling for `upper_bound` returning `ranges.end()` (which works unless the input itself could be `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, in which case you do need some special handling).

Here is a full example:

```
#include <map>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

struct ColorArguments { int a; int b; int c; int d; };

void setColor(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ", " << d << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, ColorArguments> const ranges = {
        { 100,                             { 255, 0   , 0, 1 } },
        { 1000,                            { 0,   255 , 0, 2 } },
        { std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), { 0,   0,    0, 3 } }
    };

    int const errorNumber = 500;

    auto const iter = ranges.upper_bound(errorNumber);

    setColor(
        iter->second.a,
        iter->second.b,
        iter->second.c,
        iter->second.d
    );
}
```

---

Algorithmic complexity aside, this solution also turns static, hard-coded `if-else` logic into data, which can be modified or read dynamically at run-time. Even if you don't use it for your specific problem here, it's a technique to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much, finally one person, who takes this question serious and gave a very well answer! Thank you so much! :)